# How to select specific databases in a backup retention policy maintenance plan cleanup task?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, maintenance, maintenance-plans

I have full backups of three different databases. Right now all of their backups follow the same retention policy, but I need to setup the retention to a different amount of time for each database.

In the Maintenance Cleanup Task screen I see it just searches the whole backup folder for any backup files to remove. Is there any way to specify the databases I want this to run for or is the only way to do this is by setting the folder directly to the backup folder of that database? (E.g. I'd have to change the folder to Y:\SQLBackup\Full\Database1)

If so, then do I need to create a retention policy maintenance plan for each database then?

[image: Maintenance Cleanup Task]